# parser to convert values including fraction to decimal

Tags: apex, string, number

I have one Fields planValue_c set as %age in salesforce.
Possible inputs when reading from file  are like

```
20 -Integer
20 2/3- Integer with fraction ( space is delimiter)
2/3 - Fraction
```

Assuming integer with fraction will always have space a determiner.

Decimal.value(String) is throwing error on in case fraction. as when something like 20 2/3 is assigined to %age its throwing error.

I was trying for some logic like

```
if(String.isNotBlank(input)){
    if (String(input).contains(space))// It means it has fraction, What is expression for space would it be /t or '' 
    {
        Decimal value=String.SubstringAfter(space);// to separte fraction after space
        //Math.round(value)// How can i get fraction value here calculated to decimal

    }

    else if(String.size()=1)// Means it can only either fraction or Interger
        try {
            Decimal newInput=decimal.value(input);//if it is integer it should pass
        }
    catch (TypeException t){

        //if it was fraction sinlge like 2/3 it should come here

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just insist on the standard decimal format? This functionality seems of dubious value.

Comment: Value is comming from some third party. We cannot control them. there users are sending all three formats and we have % age type field at salesforce as buisness want it to use into reports

Comment: Can you just trim the fraction entirely? Seems like it could be good enough accuracy.

Comment: Actually as this involves ratings system, this will impact premium they want to show on reports. When many records got trimmed this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider regular expressions here:

```
public static Decimal parse(String input)
{
    try
    {
        return Decimal.valueOf(input);
    }
    catch (TypeException t)
    {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*\\/\\s*(\\d+)').matcher(input);            if (m.find()) return Decimal.valueOf(m.group(1)) +
            Decimal.valueOf(m.group(2)) / Decimal.ValueOf(m.group(3));
    }
    return null;
}
```

The expression itself is pretty straightforward as these things go. You can always feed a regular expression into **[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Da1FYa/1)** and get great explanations:

> ```
> (\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+)
> ```
>
> - **1st Capturing Group** `(\d+)`
>
>   - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - `\s+` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>
>   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - **2nd Capturing Group** `(\d+)`
>
>   - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
>
>   - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
> - `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
>
>   - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - **3rd Capturing Group** `(\d+)`
>
>   - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

You feed the capturing groups back into `Decimal.valueOf` using `m.group(groupNumber)`.

You can test this parser pretty easily as well:

```
system.assertEquals(1, parse('1'));
system.assertEquals(3.14, parse('3.14'));
system.assertEquals(66.67, parse('66 2/3').setScale(2));
system.assertEquals(1.5, parse('1   1 / 2'));
```

---

If you want to make the leading number optional, it gets a bit more complicated. I'll try to add an explanation tomorrow, but basically you need to:

- make the capturing group optional (`?` just after the parens)
- make the whitespace quantifier between the first and second capturing groups optional (`*` instead of `+`)
- include a whitespace character inside the first capturing group to compensate

Now that one of them might be null, it will be easier to handle these strings if you cache the groups.

```
// inside catch block
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(\\d+\\s)?\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\/\\s*(\\d+)').matcher(input);
if (!m.find()) return null;

String d1 = m.group(1), d2 = m.group(2), d3 = m.group(3);
Decimal base = String.isBlank(d1) ? 0 : Decimal.valueOf(d1.trim());
Decimal fraction = Decimal.valueOf(d2) / Decimal.valueOf(d3);
return base + fraction;
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, you are aweseome, i am getting following results..  system.debug(''+parse('66 2/3')); =66.666666666666666666666666666666667
system.debug(''+parse('2/3')); =null
system.debug(''+parse('66.89'));= 66.89

Comment: Please help me here, i have never used RegEX, could you please guide me where to put ?..I am really thankful to you

Comment: Thanks Adrian, it was really helpful..let me try some testing around it

Comment: It was so cool, i do not have words to express. I wish i could be a good programmer like you in some time in my life.. Thanks a lot again. :)